# Orthgonal basis in $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix any $k$ odd. Consider $\mathcal{S}$, the subset of $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ consisting of all binary vectors which have odd number of ones.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be any set of $k$ many vectors in $\mathcal{S}$ such that every pair of vectors in $\mathcal{I}$ are orthogonal (addition and multiplication are $\mod 2$).

How many different choice of $\mathcal{I}$ is possible?

(obviously there is at least one such $\mathcal{I}$. Consider the canonical basis)

Comment: It seems to me that there will be only one: the one given by the canonical basis.

Comment: two cases $k$ is or odd or either even

Comment: @janmarqz but the $k$ is odd by the assumption.

Comment: @Larara Is there any reference or proof?

Comment: @anirbanbasak see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ with given property. Then treating them as row-vectors we can create $k!$ many $k \times k$ matrices $O$ such that $O O^T=I$.

That is $O$ is in the orthogonal group $\mathcal{O}(k,2)$. Now we can use the following to get a bound:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317262?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a counterexample for

> $$\mathcal{I}=\{\text{canonical basis}\}\; \text{only}.$$

Consider $k=5$, and the following set of $k=5$ vectors all of them having an odd number of $1$'s:

```
(1,1,0,1,0)
(1,0,0,1,1)
(0,0,1,0,0)
(0,1,0,1,1)
(1,1,0,0,1)
```

Comment: I do not see how to argue that ``there will be some $j$ such that $n(i,j)$ is not even''.

Comment: @anirbanbasak sorry for the wrong answer.  I found a mistake on my argument of ''there will be some $j$ such that $n(i,j)$ is not even''. Also I tried several times to find a counterexample and indeed found one: the one in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Larara. Generalizing your example, for any $\ell$ odd one can construct an orthogonal basis having odd number of $1$'s in each of basis vectors in the following way:

Choose a subset of $[\ell]:=\{1,2,\ldots,\ell\}$ of cardinality $\ell-1$. Denote that set by $\mathcal{S}_\ell$. Take the canonical vector with $1$ in the $[\ell]\setminus \mathcal{S}_\ell$ place, and $0$ elsewhere. 

Next, choose another subset $\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_\ell \subset \mathcal{S}_\ell$ of cardinality $\ell-2$. 

For our next vector put all $1$ in $\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_\ell$.

Comment: Now need to choose the remaining $\ell-2$ vectors. To do so, choose any subset of $\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_\ell$ of cardinality $\ell-3$. Put all $1$ there, and put one more $1$ in $\mathcal{S}_\ell \setminus \tilde{\mathcal{S}}_\ell$. Note that there are $\ell-2$ such choices. This makes sure all these next $\ell-2$ vectors have $\ell-2$ many ones. And one can check that these vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Generalizing the above, for any odd $k$ we can choose $\{\ell_j\}$, each of them odd, and $\sum_j \ell_j =k$, and then repeat the above procedure for each such $\ell_j$.

Comment: Now the question is if this mechanism is the only way one can construct an orthogonal basis such that all vectors have odd number of ones.